# How can I use Language Constant in google ads python?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have a code that give me suggestion of keywords from google ads api.

in this code I have a section that select language with language id but in new version of Google Ads API (V13) it's deprecated and removed.

```
language_rn = client.get_service(
        "LanguageConstantService"
    ).language_constant_path(language_id)
```

What is the alternative of LanguageConstantService Now?
How can I set Language in my request?

I find my code from link below:
https://www.danielherediamejias.com/python-keyword-planner-google-ads-api/

---

The Error is:

> ValueError: Specified service LanguageConstantService does not exist
> in Google Ads API v13.

Answer (score 2):

I found out we can use GoogleAdsService for it:

```
language_rn = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService").language_constant_path(
        language_id
    )
```

check this out:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/samples/generate-keyword-ideas

Answer (score 0):

"""Try this:"""

```
campaign_criterion_service = client.get_service("CampaignCriterionService")

# Create the campaign criterion operation
campaign_criterion_operation = client.get_type(
    "CampaignCriterionOperation"
)
campaign_criterion = campaign_criterion_operation.create
campaign_criterion.campaign = campaign_resource_name
#list of language constants: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#expandable-7
campaign_criterion.language.language_constant=language_constant

campaign_criterion_response = campaign_criterion_service.mutate_campaign_criteria(
    customer_id=customer_id, operations=[campaign_criterion_operation]
)
print(
    "Campaign criterion with resource name "
    f'"{campaign_criterion_response.results[0].resource_name}" was '
    "modified."
)
```